# Trouble in editing an open source project. MERN E-Commerce app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, e-commerce, mern

I have cloned one open source mern stack ecommerce application. But I can't edit anything in client side.Even I have deleted client folder completely. But still executing the UI completely . I don't know from where it is fetching. Some one please help me!

About the project
I havn't seen any project like that. It is working in single localhost.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beco4.png)

**The complete code :
https://github.com/mohamedsamara/mern-ecommerce**

nodemon.json:

```
 {
  "ignore": [
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "client",
    "build",
    "dist"
  ],
  "verbose": false,
  "watch": ["server"],
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  }
}
```

Scripts in package.josn:

```
 "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production  --config webpack/webpack.prod.js",
    "dev:client": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server  --config webpack/webpack.dev.js",
    "dev:server": "nodemon",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel dev:*",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "seed:db": "node server/utils/seed.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JoseLora That is because I don't know what is happening. The project is completely ok and no single errors. But the problem is I cannot do any changes in design. So I deleted the client folder. Unfortunatly no error and still rendering the UI. I don't know from where it is fetching the code.